# Cast Observable Collection from base Class to inherited class

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm writing a WPF application and I'm currently refactoring some reused code to a base ViewModel Class which my other viewmodels can inherit from.

One Property field on this base class is

```
public class MessageParentBase
{
  MessageParentBase() {}

  public string Name;
}

internal ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase> _GridData = new ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase>();
```

I have a subsequent property declaration

```
public ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase> GridData
    {
        get { return _GridData; }
        set { _GridData = value; }
    }
```

This works great and everything my issue is that the inerited classes actually use the follow class

```
Public class ChatMessage : MessageParentBase
{
    public string Message;
}
```

and the view contains a grid of data which is bound to this GridData property but the column which should be bound to the Message field from the ChatMessage class is blank and the fields found in the MessageParentBase class are populated.

So I presume there is an issue with the view not knowing to cast up to the ChatMessage from the MessageParentBase class.

Can I inform the view that the objects will be of the type "ChatMessage".

I did try moving the property declaration up to the inherited viewmodel as

```
public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> GridData
    {
        get { return _GridData; }
        set { _GridData = value; }
    }
```

but this gives me the following error:-

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'

Do I need to cast at the view level or can I change the viewmodels to implement this better?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Emlyn

Comment: What do you mean by *cast at view level*? Are you binding the base viewmodel and wanting to show the ChatMessage properties? Your question is not clear. Show us what/how are you binding the view model to the view.

Comment: Also, show the messageParentBase class.  As it stands, your question is hard to follow.

Comment: Hopefully my edit helps explain my question some more.

Answer (score 0):

Change the collection to this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase> GridData { get; set; }
```

then add into your constructor

```
this.GridData = new ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase>();
```

Since WPF uses reflection to retrieve bound data from the data context it should be able to get the values of the derived classes stored in that collection.

Also when you run your application check the output window with Debug selected, the XAML engine will output any binding errors there.

Comment: I've tried this approach but as the GridData is declared as
    ObservableCollection<MessageParentBase>()

it still does not display the fields from the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should contain a list with the type that your grid will show (in this case, the ChatMessage type). You can still use the inheritance to call common methods, but the binded list must be of the ChatMessage type

Comment: Ah I was thinking this was the case. Is there someway I can have some reference in base class as a lot of the functionality I was hoping to move to this class is not looking for specific of the ChatMessage class and this observable collection. Otherwise I'm going to have a lot of repeated code for each viewmodel which uses a different derived class from MessageParentBase.

Comment: When you get the selected item, the object that will be returned will have the ChatMessage type. Since this class inherits from MessageParentBase, you'll have access to all its methods normally (I´m supposing this is your doubt)

Comment: My real issue is how to remove the repeated code which needs to reference the GridData observable collection (But is only interested in the MessageParentBase class fields) in the base class of the ViewModel while still being able to initiate the observable collection as a ChatMessage one.

I thought I could declare the field in the base viewmodel and then Declare the property in the derived ViewModel but I'm being told I cannot implicity convert from one ObservableCollection to another even though one class inherits from the other.